# Can I create an if statement from an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Google Chrome extension that allows users to save parameters to the chrome.storage area by using a form in the extensions options.html page. The parameters they enter get combined into an object that is saved to chrome.storage.local.

When they visit a website I load up that object from storage in my content script. I then need to create `if` statements based on the data the user provided.

Given a variable like this (value set by me or pulled from another source, not the user). Other examples would be things like the `document.referrer` of the page the user is on, or the `.href` property of an `<a>` tag on the page.

```
var variable = "foo"; // this variable and its value of 'foo' here is created by me
```

And this object (provided by the user):

```
const ifStatement = {
  "operator": "and", // &&, logical operator selected by user
  "conditions": [
    [
      "variable", // a variable name saved to storage as a string. the user chose it from a list of provided variables
      "===",      // comparison operator saved as a string, selected by user
      "foo"       // custom string entered by user, intended by them to match against the variable they identified
    ],
    [
      "variable",
      "!==",
      "bar"
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can I create an `if` statement that looks like this?

```
if ( variable === "foo" && variable !== "bar" ) {
  // do something
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the UI the user would be using to provide me with the values in my `ifStatement` object. Maybe this will help visualize what I'm doing.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can, but you will need to create your own parser...

Comment: Be extremely wary of anything involving `eval()` and user input.

Comment: Your grammar is ambiguous - there's no way of telling whether the string `"path"` refers to a literal string (per the RHS of your operators) or the name of a variable.

Comment: @Alnitak Edited to hopefully be more clear. The string in the object is a reference to a variables name. So I'd need to match that string to a variable in order to use it in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a function that interprets the object provided by the user. For the variable(s) you provide, I would suggest to define them as property(ies) of a single object. So instead of:

```
var path = "foo"
```

... you would have:

```
var vars = { path: "foo" }
```

The function would take `vars` and the user-provided object. It would return either `false` or `true`. With such a result you can easily write an `if` statement. The core question is really to produce the boolean value.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
function evalBoolean(vars, {operator, conditions}) {
    return conditions[operator === "and" ? "every" : "some"](([name, cmp, value]) => ({
            "===": (a, b) => a === b,
            "!==": (a, b) => a !== b,
            "<"  : (a, b) => a < b,
            ">"  : (a, b) => a < b,
            "<=" : (a, b) => a <= b,
            ">=" : (a, b) => a >= b,
        })[cmp](vars[name], value)
    );
}

// Demo
var vars = { path: "foo" };

const expression = {
  "operator": "and",
  "conditions": [
    [
      "path",
      "===",
      "foo"
    ],
    [
      "path",
      "!==",
      "bar"
    ]
  ]
}

console.log(evalBoolean(vars, expression));
```